# check Jid (jabber id) registered in the xmpp server - iOS xmpp framework

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat, xmppframework

I am working on the chat application. I want to check does the entered jid is registered with xmpp server or not. I am using robbiehanson framework.
If anyone has any idea or link please share.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to look for messages in the method
`- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotAuthenticate:(NSXMLElement *)error` for the not-authorized stream as defined in the [RFC-6120](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#sasl-errors)

*6.5.10.  not-authorized
The authentication failed because the initiating entity did not provide proper credentials, or because some generic authentication failure has occurred but the receiving entity does not wish to disclose specific information about the cause of the failure; sent in reply to a  element or an  element with initial response data.
    I: 
         [ ... ]

```
R: <failure xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>
     <not-authorized/>
   </failure>
```

Security Warning: This error condition includes but is not limited to the case of incorrect credentials or a **nonexistent username.** In order to discourage directory harvest attacks, no differentiation is made between incorrect credentials and a nonexistent username.*